# How to enable hot-reload for Svelte on a development server?

Tags: javascript, web, server, svelte, hot-reload

I'm working on a project which is written in PHP on a development server, and want to rewrite it in Svelte. Ideally I would like to have it on this server, acting as if I had run `npm run dev` locally (i.e. the page would automatically recompile after each edit.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes I have - I know how to put it on the server, but I want it to live update. I.e. I want it to recompile on each save, so that I can access the latest version in real time simply by visiting the server in the browser.

Comment: A quick Google search turns up this: https://progressivewebninja.com/how-to-configure-svelte-rollup-server-hot-reload/